# Configurating Apache for Symfony

Tags: php, apache-2.2

My full path to the Symfony installation is: `C:\xampp\htdocs\development\sfprojects\jobeet\lib\vendor\symfony`, but when I proceed with the installation following the tutorial on symfony's page all my newly created directories are in `C:\`. I talk about - `apps`, `config`, `web` and so on. I've reached the final stage where I should change the Apache configuration file and get everything done and working but I encounter a problem again. In the official site it's said to add this:

> > Be sure to only have this line once in your configuration
> >     NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080
> >
> > This is the configuration for your project
> >     Listen 127.0.0.1:8080

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
  DocumentRoot "/home/sfprojects/jobeet/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/home/sfprojects/jobeet/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf /home/sfprojects/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
  <Directory "/home/sfprojects/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And change:
On Windows, you need to replace the `Alias` line with something like:

```
Alias /sf "c:\dev\sfprojects\jobeet\lib\vendor\symfony\data\web\sf"
```

And `/home/sfprojects/jobeet/web`

should be replaced with:

`c:\dev\sfprojects\jobeet\web`

I tried to make this working for my installation using my paths but when I edit the config file I still can't open the start page. So could someone help me with what I should change to make this work for me and also I was thinking of copying the directories from `C:\` to my `htdocs` directory in XAMPP, but I'm not sure if this gonna work and honestly I prefer to stick to the guide and just follow the steps there adjusting them the less I could.

Comment: When you say its not working, what happens when you go to [http://172.0.0.1:8080](http://172.0.0.1:8080)?

Comment: I get this :
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had problems with this too, especially when adding multiple projects. I wouldn't put the project inside the XAMPP folders because XAMPP does some weird stuff. I recommend letting XAMPP be XAMPP and putting your project somewhere else off of your C root.

Here's what works for me in Windows 7 + XAMPP (with multiple vhosts):

```
NameVirtualHost *

Listen 127.0.0.1:80

<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName local.myproject
  DocumentRoot "C:/development/sfprojects/myproject/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "C:/development/sfprojects/myproject/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf "C:/development/sfprojects/myproject/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf"
  <Directory "C:/development/sfprojects/myproject/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And... HOSTS file:

```
127.0.0.1  local.myproject
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to point the web server to the correct folder:
Add all of this to the end of httpd.conf

```
# Be sure to only have this line once in your configuration
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080

# This is the configuration for your project
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
  DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\development\sfprojects\jobeet\web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/development/sfprojects/jobeet/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf "C:\xampp\htdocs\development\sfprojects\jobeet\lib\vendor\symfony\data\web\sf"
  <Directory "/development/sfprojects/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then go to http://~localhost~:8080/ or localhost:8080 to see your Symfony project. You don't have to edit the host file yet.